# c++ std::shared_ptr Error C2664

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, c2664

I am using a `std::shared_ptr` to point to a Node

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    class Node
    {
       T data;
       std::shared_ptr<Node> link;
       Node(T data, std::shared_ptr<Node> link);
    };
    void push(T data);
    std::shared_ptr<Node> top;
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::Node::Node(T data, std::shared_ptr<typename A<T>::Node> link) : 
data(data), link(link)
{
}

template<typename T>
void A<T>::push(T item)
{
    if (top == nullptr)
    {
       top = std::make_shared<typename A<T>::Node>(new typename 
                                                    A<T>::Node(item, nullptr));
    }
    else
    {
       top = std::make_shared<typename A<T>::Node>(new typename A<T>::Node(item, top));
    }
}
```

The resulting  declarations and definitions results in the compiler error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664   'Stack::Node::Node(const Stack::Node &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Stack::Node *' to 'const Stack::Node &'   memory  901

What do I need to change to conform to `<memory>`?

Comment: Please post the full error message, not just the first line.

Comment: And a more complete example that actually doesn't compile. What you have here compiles fine in VS 2017.

Comment: `std::make_shared` takes as an argument a reference to an object, but you are using `new` to make a pointer, thus, probably, your `cannot convert argument 1 from 'Stack::Node *' to 'const Stack::Node &'` error.

Comment: You mean `<memory>`, not `memory.h`.

Comment: @KenY-N The only other information on this error I have is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2664)&rd=true)

Comment: @aschepler Thank you and corrected

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am using Visual Studio 2015 and `<memory>` is not compiling correctly.  Did you set up VS2017 to not ignore warnings and instead treat them as errors?

Comment: I have no warnings in *just the code you posted*. If I fix the issues where you didn't make the constructor public in Node, or the Node definition and push function public in A, and I add headers and make a main I can duplicate your error. My point was, your example is not complete, and the error you posted was not generated from the posted code. (Stack != A) The error is also not complete since you posted 1 out of the 25 lines it generates.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That is the point though.  You have to build a real example and then the warning which becomes an error is plainly visible.  As I pointed out, that is all the compilation error info I have as presented to me by Visual Studio 2015 with a link directly to Microsoft's page describing it in more detail.  That written, what I posted above does generate the error and an answer has been posted correcting that error; namely don't use `new` with `std::make_shared` and it works, tested and all.  Answer accepted.

Comment: It's your job when you ask a question to make a complete example, not ours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor of `std::shared_ptr<T>` accepts a pointer to `T` which you have created with `new`.

The function `std::make_shared<T>(args...)` does the `new` for you instead.  The arguments you pass to `make_shared` will be passed on to the constructor of `T`.  So you should almost never pass it a pointer created by `new` (unless you really want to `new` a `T`, and then pass that pointer as an argument to create another `T`!).

So for example, instead of:

```
std::make_shared<typename A<T>::Node>(
   new typename A<T>::Node(item, top))
```

do just:

```
std::make_shared<typename A<T>::Node>(item, top)
```

(By the way, you don't actually need most of those `typename A<T>::` qualifiers.  Just plain `Node` is in scope whenever you're in the scope of `A<T>` or `A<T>::Node`, both in the class definitions and member definitions of that class after the member name.  `A<T>::Node` without the `typename` would also work in those contexts because of the "member of the current instantiation" rule.)